# How to flatten and output two multidimensional arrays and print combinations of paired values?

Tags: php

I have 2 input arrays:

```
$data1 = array (
    0 => 0,
    1 => array ( 0 => 4, 1 => 8, ),
    2 => 0,
    3 => array ( 0 => 2, 1 => 6, 2 => 10, ),
    4 => array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 5, ),
    5 => array ( 0 => 3, 1 => 7, 2 => 11, ),
)

$data2 = array (
    0 => 0,
    1 => array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 5, ),
    2 => array ( 0 => 4, 1 => 8, ),
    3 => 0,
)
```

While reading the leaf nodes from the first array, I mean to iterate all of the leaf nodes of the second array and print all of the paired combinations.

My trouble is that only the last value from the subarrays in `$data1` are being printed AND only the last value from `$data2` is being printed.

My code:

```
foreach ($data1 as $sourcevalue){
    if( is_array($sourcevalue) == "1")
    {
        foreach ($sourcevalue as $value)
        {
            $source=$value;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $source=$sourcevalue;
    }

    foreach ($data2 as $endvalue){
        if( is_array($endvalue) == "1")
        {
            foreach ($endvalue as $value1){
                $end=$value1;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $end=$endvalue;
        }
    }
    echo $source." ".$end."<br>";   
}
```

My current output:

```
0 0
8 0
0 0
10 0
5 0
11 0
```

Desired output:

```
0 0
0 1
0 5
0 4
0 8
0 0
4 0
4 1
4 5
4 4
4 8
4 0
8 0
8 1
8 5
8 4
8 8
8 0
0 0
0 1
0 5
0 4
0 8
0 0
2 0
2 1
2 5
2 4
2 8
2 0
6 0
6 1
6 5
6 4
6 8
6 0
10 0
10 1
10 5
10 4
10 8
10 0
1 0
1 1
1 5
1 4
1 8
1 0
5 0
5 1
5 5
5 4
5 8
5 0
3 0
3 1
3 5
3 4
3 8
3 0
7 0
7 1
7 5
7 4
7 8
7 0
11 0
11 1
11 5
11 4
11 8
11 0
```

How can I amend my code to display all combos?

Comment: Worst thing to compare `is_array($endvalue) == "1"`: `is_array` already returns boolean, no need to convert to string!

Comment: Can you explain what you try to do? As you output only last element in inner array, any previous is overwritten and never used

Comment: You are doing foreach inside foreach and every time you loop you do `$end=$value1`, so you just erase the value before and put the last one. Add some echo every time you get a new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo intermediate elements too, not only last one

```php
foreach ($data1 as $sourcevalue){
    if (is_array($sourcevalue)) {
        foreach ($sourcevalue as $value) {
            printData2($value);
        }
    } else {
        printData2($sourcevalue);
    }
}

function printData2($source) {
    foreach ($data2 as $endvalue){
        if (is_array($endvalue)){
            foreach ($endvalue as $value1){
                pr($source, $value1);
            }
        } else  {
            pr($source, $endvalue);
        }
    }
}

function pr($source, $end) {
    echo "{$source} {$end}<br>";
}
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5bd6131528aa4db81347adf683bf616175e8d487)

Comment: i get error Call to undefined function printData2()

Comment: my bad i was putting the function part inside the isset button so war getting the eoor...moment i put it outside it worked perfectly fine...thank u so so much

Comment: @Justinas how do i get the key too for each value

Comment: @Justinas how can i pulll the key of the value too  like when its 1=>8 then how do i pull out the 1 into a variable

Comment: @angel `foreach ($data1 as $key => $value)`

Answer (score 0):

The data in array 2 never changes while processing, so it is better practice to prepare/flatten the data to avoid redundant `is_array()` calls while iterating nested loops.

One way of doing this is to use `array_merge_recursive()` to visit only leaf nodes (non-iterables) and generate a one-dimensional array (`$flat2`).

Another good trick, instead of making `is_array()` calls while iterating `$data1` is to cast the elements (whether they are iterable or not) as arrays.  If a non-iterable element (`$e`) is cast as an array, it becomes the lone value in the new array.  In other words, `$e` becomes `[$e]`.

These two steps go a long way to cleaning up your code.

In my snippet below, use two foreach loops to traverse `$data1`, then a third loop to iterate `$flat2`, and finally, use `printf()` to cleanly format and output your data.

Note, I am including the first level keys from `$data1` per your request under Justinas' answer.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jOAto))

```
$flat2 = [];
array_walk_recursive($data2, function($v) use(&$flat2) {
    $flat2[] = $v;
});

foreach ($data1 as $k => $e) {
    foreach ((array)$e as $v) {
        foreach ($flat2 as $f) {
            printf("%d: %d %d\n", $k, $v, $f);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or with only language constructs, you can use the same array-casting technique on both arrays and nested the second sets of nested loops inside the first set of nested loops.  This will generate fewer variables, make 1 less function call, and be more concise.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2vjCc))

```
foreach ($data1 as $k => $e1) {
    foreach ((array)$e1 as $v1) {
        foreach ($data2 as $e2) {
            foreach ((array)$e2 as $v2) {
                printf("%d: %d %d\n", $k, $v1, $v2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0: 0 0
0: 0 1
0: 0 5
0: 0 4
0: 0 8
0: 0 0
1: 4 0
1: 4 1
1: 4 5
1: 4 4
1: 4 8
1: 4 0
1: 8 0
1: 8 1
1: 8 5
1: 8 4
1: 8 8
1: 8 0
2: 0 0
2: 0 1
2: 0 5
2: 0 4
2: 0 8
2: 0 0
3: 2 0
3: 2 1
3: 2 5
3: 2 4
3: 2 8
3: 2 0
3: 6 0
3: 6 1
3: 6 5
3: 6 4
3: 6 8
3: 6 0
3: 10 0
3: 10 1
3: 10 5
3: 10 4
3: 10 8
3: 10 0
4: 1 0
4: 1 1
4: 1 5
4: 1 4
4: 1 8
4: 1 0
4: 5 0
4: 5 1
4: 5 5
4: 5 4
4: 5 8
4: 5 0
5: 3 0
5: 3 1
5: 3 5
5: 3 4
5: 3 8
5: 3 0
5: 7 0
5: 7 1
5: 7 5
5: 7 4
5: 7 8
5: 7 0
5: 11 0
5: 11 1
5: 11 5
5: 11 4
5: 11 8
5: 11 0
```